# AVG functions problem

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, average

I have table with structure

```
id
YearBorn
sex
livelen
```

I need to receive output result table of average livelength(livelen) for both sexes
with struct

```
year, len1(female), len2(male)
```

My query

```
SELECT YearBorn , 
AVG(IF(sex='F', LiveLen, 0)) len1(female),
AVG(IF(sex='M', LiveLen, 0)) len2(male)
FROM persons p
GROUP BY YearBorn
```

but it is not working properly
Average value that is returned is the result of dividing  sum **livlen** of fem(male) to the total number of records **livlen** , but not exactly to the number of **f** or m**.**
What can you say about it

Answer (score 3):

Replace `0` with `NULL`. Otherwise, the value counts too:

```
70 + 0 + 90
------------ = 50
     3

70 + 90
------- = 80
   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your own AVG

```
SELECT
   YearBorn , 
   SUM(IF(sex='F', LiveLen, 0))/COUNT(IF(sex='F', LiveLen, 0)) len1(female),
   SUM(IF(sex='F', LiveLen, 0))/COUNT(IF(sex='F', LiveLen, 0)) len2(male)
FROM persons p
GROUP BY YearBorn
```

Or use NULL which is ignored in aggregates. 0 is a value

```
SELECT
   YearBorn , 
   AVG(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN LiveLen ELSE NULL END) len1(female),
   AVG(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN LiveLen ELSE NULL END) len2(male)
FROM persons p
GROUP BY YearBorn
```

CASE is more portable then inline IF too

Comment: @a1ex07: it is, but a CASE with no ELSE can look odd :-)